# vendor class not found in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I use [unisharp file manager](https://github.com/UniSharp/laravel-filemanager/blob/master/docs/installation.md) in my project. on my local machine everything works fine, but on remote server it throws error `[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException] Class 'Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider' not found` 
in `config/app.php` everything's correct

```
    /*FileMananger*/
    Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider::class,
    Intervention\Image\ImageServiceProvider::class,
    /*CKEditor*/
    Unisharp\Ckeditor\ServiceProvider::class,
```

there is directory `unisharp` in vedor(so all files and directories are there). when i try to run composer install/update i get this error again. so everything in its right place, but laravel doesn't see this class.

comoser.json

```
{
"name": "laravel/laravel",
"description": "The Laravel Framework.",
"keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
"license": "MIT",
"type": "project",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/framework": "5.3.*",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "~2.1.0",
    "appzcoder/crud-generator": "^1.2",
    "laravelcollective/html": "^5.3",
    "lavary/laravel-menu": "dev-master",
    "nesbot/carbon": "^1.21",
    "laracasts/flash": "^2.0",
    "spatie/laravel-medialibrary": "^3.11",
    "firebase/php-jwt": "^4.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "mockery/mockery": "0.9.*",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
    "symfony/css-selector": "3.1.*",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "3.1.*"
},
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "database"
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    },
    "files": [
        "app/Http/helpers.php"
    ]
},
"autoload-dev": {
    "classmap": [
        "tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
},
"scripts": {
    "post-root-package-install": [
        "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
    ],
    "post-create-project-cmd": [
        "php artisan key:generate"
    ],
    "post-install-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postInstall",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ],
    "post-update-cmd": [
        "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postUpdate",
        "php artisan optimize"
    ]
},
"config": {
    "preferred-install": "dist"
}
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the command `composer dump-autoload` and also `php artisan optimize`?

Comment: I don't see `Laravelfilemanager` package in your composer.json's require list?

Comment: thanks guys for reply. when I run `php artisan` it gives that error(no matter which command). i run dumpautoload it doesn't help

Comment: I added Laravelfilemanager in `composer.json` but same result

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to comment those lines in `config/app.php` and run `composer require unisharp/laravel-filemanager` again.

You can't set up service providers before they are downloaded through composer.

Comment: Worked for me. Thhank you

Answer (score 2):

You need to run:

```
composer require unisharp/laravel-filemanager
```

Comment: By 'installed' do you mean added to your `composer.json`?  Run `composer dump-auto` in the root of the project

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your config/app.php unisharp providers is matched with the content in folder vendor unisharp composer.json
check below:

**Config/app.php**
[image]

**vendor/unisharp-composer.json**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

the solution is very easy :)
just make sure you have this in your service provider:

```html
Unisharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider::class,
```

not this one:

```html
UniSharp\Laravelfilemanager\LaravelFilemanagerServiceProvider::class,
```